# system printing service not available ubuntu 18.10

Tags: printing, systemd, 18.10

I have a problem with the system printing service:

My usb printer used to work just fine, and then I tried to a setup print-server - the whole system hanged up, and after reboot, no matter what I do, I have this message from the GUI settings for printers ...

System printing service not available:
[image: system printing service not available]

I was trying to restart `cups.service` and `cups.socket` as advised in :

[Ubuntu 18.04 LTS -- Printing Service Not Available](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065068/ubuntu-18-04-lts-printing-service-not-available)
[Printing service not available](https://askubuntu.com/questions/575136/printing-service-not-available)

and `cups.socket` stays "green" until I look up into the GUI settings for printers, which seems to do something that resets `cups.socket` again ...

Here is a screenshot of the "best" cups situation:
[image: services are not dead]

and that's how it looks like right after I check out the GUI printing settings:
[image: services fail]

I also tried to reinstall cups, - no luck here either.

[image: system info]

Any help/advice is appreciated, as I really don't want to reinstall the system, and chances are everything would crash again after I attempt to setup the print-server ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. The solution given in [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065068/ubuntu-18-04-lts-printing-service-not-available/1106534#1106534)  solves the problem.

There is a default configuration file which should be installed in `/usr/share/cups/cupsd.conf.default` so I ran:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/cups/cupsd.conf.default /etc/cups/cupsd.conf
sudo service cups restart
```

Comment: `systemctl status cups.socket` is still failing, but the rest seems to be working! cups is back; printers sections in settings is back etc. Looks like I did something wrong the first time I've tried it.