# Printers Settings UI crashes, system printing service unavailable

Tags: drivers, printing, settings, canon

In Ubuntu 20.04 in the GUI settings, printers - I get the message 'Sorry! The system printing service doesn't seem to be available'.

I have a Canon MF643Cdw printer on wi-fi. CUPS seems to be working fine (no errors in systemctl). I can even print the test page from localhost:631 using either no driver or the canon UFR 2 driver,

system-config-printer-gnome 1.5.12-0ubuntu1.1 is installed.

I've tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1092392/system-printing-service-not-available-ubuntu-18-10) to no avail. I've also tried purging and installing cups again with apt.

The canon printer utility can't find the printer in it's network IP address either.

Interestingly, lpinfo -m says: **Bad file descriptor**

Any help/advice is appreciated.

Comment: **Bad file descriptor** usually means cups daemom is not running.

Comment: @brian_p I've checked with _systemctl status cups_. All is running with no errors. The webpage with cups settings is also running. Should I check the daemon any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the name of the localhost cups server into **/etc/cups/client.conf**

```
ServerName localhost:631
```

Restart the cups service

```
sudo systemctl restart cups
```

The UI works now.